# How can I add 3 buttons to a listview on Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'd like to customize each line of a List View and make them show up in the following way:

[List View Buttons http://raphaeu.com/img_botoes.jpg](http://raphaeu.com/img_botoes.jpg)

In the picture above, I will, of course, replace the numbers for images. But I need to make each one of those places "clickable", that is, each numbered place must have a different touch event attached to it.

How would I go on doing that?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Custom List Adapter like Andro.. states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856411/add-a-button-in-a-listview):

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  ArrayList<SingleElementDetails> allElementDetails;
private Context con; 
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleElementDetails> results) {
    allElementDetails = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    con=context;
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview1, null);

    Button bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt);
    TextView textview1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dishname_entry);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_entry);
    TextView textview3=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_entry);
    textview1.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).getDishName());
    textview2.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).getCategory());
    textview3.setText(allElementDetails.get(position).getDescription());



    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(con,MainActivity.class);
            con.startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
    return convertView;
}    
}
```

Just have to tweak it a little bit for what you're trying to do. Everything you need though is pretty much in that class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom adapter class, extending from BaseAdapter. In it, you can inflate any layout for your rows you wish. There're tons of tutorials for this, search for 'listview custom adapter'.